# C++ invalid use of nonstatic data member

Tags: c++

I have looked around and have sen this question asked a fair bit but I the problems they are having seem different to mine.
I am only a beginner so I find it kind of hard to understand whats wrong with my program. Here is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Character
{
    int health;
    string action;

    public:
    void setHealth(int hp) {health = hp;}
    void setAction(string act) {action = act;}
    int getHealth() {return health;}
    string getAction() {return action;}
};

int main()
{
    int difficulty;

    Character player;
    player.setHealth(15);

    Character enemy;

    cout << "What difficulty would you like to play? easy = 1,  medium = 2, hard = 3 ";
    cin >> difficulty;

    switch (difficulty)
    {
        case 1 : enemy.setHealth(10); break;
        case 2 : enemy.setHealth(15); break;
        case 3 : enemy.setHealth(20); break;
    }

    cout << "\nEnemy health = " << enemy.getHealth << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the error message I get:  In function 'int main()':
36:39: error: invalid use of non-static member function

It appears the problem is at the cout at the bottom of the main function.
Please help!

Comment: `getHealth` is a function, so you need the parenthesis to call it `enemy.getHealth()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getHealth() is a class method, not a member, so it should be:

```
cout << "\nEnemy health = " << enemy.getHealth() << endl;
```